# Владыко или владыка при обращении?

Tags: склонение

Допустимо ли использовать форму "владыко" при обращении в значении "верховный повелитель, властитель" или она применима лишь к церковнослужителям?

Answer (score 1):

Владыко — слово звательного падежа церковнославянского языка — допустимое при обращении в письмах, заявлениях, прошениях: *Благослови, владыко, — начал дьякон; Ваше Преосвященство, досточтимейший и дорогой Владыко!*

В именительном же падеже — Владыка: *Владыка Филарет благословил вам; Высокопреосвященнейший Владыка*.

1. одно из имен Божьих, указывающих на Него как на Царя, господствующего над всем Своим творением (Быт.15:2);
2. наименование епископа, архиепископа и митрополита. https://azbyka.ru/vladyka

Слав.1. Верховный повелитель, властитель; 2. Господин, владелец. https://slovar-russkogo-yazyka-xviii-v.

Answer (score 1):

Допустимо, когда хочется придать речи специфический оттенок. **Владыко** это [звательный падеж](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/162094) от **владыка**. Сюда же относятся слова **старче, батько** итд:

> Звательный падеж иногда встречается в литературе либо в целях
> **архаизации**, либо в цитатах из церковнославянских текстов и молитв,
> либо для «**украинизации**» речи героев-украинцев.